# How to dynamically create a html page?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I've a page that access a web service.

The index page calls, onLoad, a webservice method to get a list of databases.
I want to display the results on a list of buttons, each containing a database name.

Using only html and jquery/js, what is the best way to dynamically create this page?

Comment: In what format is the data returned from the webservice?

Comment: @999 the data comes in json, but that I can process it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try jquery template, you can find it here : http://api.jquery.com/category/plugins/templates/

This is from that link:

> Note: The jQuery team has decided not to take this plugin past beta.
>   It is no longer being actively developed or maintained. The docs
>   remain here for the time being (for reference) until a suitable
>   replacement template plugin is ready.

*I cant write a new answer because the question is closed so I decided write here if the you dont mind.*

There are some parts on my webpage that are dynamically displayed.
For SAVING data I use:

```
function parseJsonIfPossible(code){
    try {
        //return JSON.parse(code);
        //console.log(code);
        return $.parseJSON(code);
    } catch (e) {
        return code;
    }
}
function store(to,str){
    return parseJsonIfPossible($.ajax({
        url: core_url,//this processes the retrieved data
        global: false,
        type: "POST",
        data: {attr : to, val : str},
        dataType: "html",
        async:false,
        success: function(msg){
        //alert(msg);
        }
    }).responseText);
}
```

For GETING and DISPLAYING I use

`$('#'+file.id).html(responseText);`

I hope it helps!

Comment: it seems that you understood what was asked :)